# MSSQL Authentication Against Remote Server

Tags: sql-server, windows-authentication

I want to use MSSQL authentication for a database I'm creating for a corporation.

The problem is, due to corporate politics, the IT department will not allocate any virtual server space to us.

It also seems unwise to use a laptop sitting somewhere in the office as a server, as this is an unsecured machine.

So now, I'm going to be using a remote host.

That leaves SQL authentication as a possible solution, but the customer does not want to have another login they must use to login. They want to be able to use the login already available with their corporate domain.

That brings me to my question: Is there a way to have the MSSQL server authenticate against a domain remotely?

My first instinct is Virtual Private Network. We have such a system through our IT department, but that's going to require additional cooperation from the host and the IT department (which has been uncooperative).

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: So they've hired you to create a database for them but are refusing to host that database on one of their SQL servers? That makes no sense.

Comment: It's complicated. I'm hired under Engineering, not through IT and corporate politics gets in the way at every turn. I think that IT isn't very happy that I'm creating a database engineering would have control of. The thing is, had IT given Engineering the ability to update data on the existing database, none of this would have had to happen. But because IT makes the decisions they do and locks Engineering out, the data they have on their servers becomes outdated. Due to an unwillingness to cooperate well, my Job now exists. Under any sane conditions, none of this would be how it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL Server has to be able to access a domain controller that can authenticate the users in the corporate domain. You can either have an addition domain controller of the corporate domain near the remote SQL server, or the domain in which the SQL server resides in trusts the corporate domain.

-Sysadmin Guy

Comment: So essentially, Unless I have control over these things, it is impossible. Well, I figured as much, but I wanted to see if someone smarter than I knew a way that I did not. Thanks mate, Accepting this answer as official. Seems We'll just have to use sql authentication...